# Select by id mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select rows by id and show it. My Table is named `text`
And this is whats in the table

```
BookID Type init 
Title
Author 
PublisherName
CopyrightYeare
```

here is how i would like to call them

```
text id 10
```

by this action i get row nummber 10 and i get all the information in

```
BookID, Title, Author, PublisherName, CopyrightYeare
```

If I query this

```
text id 14
```

by this action i get row nummber 14 and i get all the information again.

```
<?php
function text($id){

$query = "SELECT * FROM text WHERE BookID =" .$id ;  

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 


$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
}

?>

<?php

echo text (14) ;
?>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem here?

Comment: and your function name doesnot match with your function calling name

Comment: you are calling displaytext() but your function definition is text() which is different, it should be match

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. I suggest you follow a decent PHP/MySQL tutorial, read up on programming basics and try again. If you still cannot get it to work, show us the problem, what you have tried and how it fails.

Comment: your function has been declared `text()`, then youre calling `displaytext()` which is a totally different function, and function `text()` has no return value at all so dont expect a value, in your present code, there is no connection to mysql at all

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a function called `displytext()` but the function is called `text()`.

The function `text()` does not return a value so the `echo` will have nothing to print.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems.

- You are using the obsolete mysql_* functions. Consider upgrading to [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- You are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Again, look at `mysqli` and read up on how to use prepared statements correctly.
- Your function is named `text`, you are calling `displaytext`
- Your function is not returning a result. At the end of the function, add `return $row;` to get the results back

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, just had another gander and here is a working code.
Problems wre

- You did not return anything from your functions
- You did not escape the $id which would leave it prone to SQL injection
- The previously stated function name,

I hope this sorts it for you. See the code bellow

```
<?php

function text($id){
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "SELECT * FROM text WHERE BookID = $id";  
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
return $row;
}
print_r(text('1'));
?>
```